# unable to connect HTTPS url in python

Tags: python, https

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('url', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('XXXX','XXXX'))
```

I am getting Below error

```
(Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(111, 'Connection refused')
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='XXXX', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url
```

Comment: maybe format your code before posting a question?

Comment: sorry for that, can you check now

Comment: Is `url` supposed to be a variable?  In your code it is passed as the string `'url'`.

Comment: in that actually i am placing my url, i just kept url as placeholder while posting the question

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you use a HTTPBasicAuth instead Proxy(maybe that corporate proxy?). 
Try to setup proxy credentials before the request.

```
$ export http_proxy='http://myproxy.example.com:1234'
$ python request.py  # Using http://myproxy.example.com:1234 as a proxy
```

Please let me know if you use a corporate proxy.

Comment: I have already set the proxy i am able to connect a http proxy, the problem is to connect to https proxy (say like app dynamics REST API)

Comment: Sometimes htts proxy use http, try:
`export https_proxy='http://myproxy.example.com:1234`

Comment: it works, but in response im just getting status as <Response [200]>, but actually the URL outputs a xml response, how to get that?

Comment: Thats good, because you just send a request and you get a 200 "OK" response. Now you should parse a url.
`from xml.etree import ElementTree` can help you